# Java dice game project: returning the values of the dice to the main method

Tags: java

I'm working on a dice game project. In the game, the user rolls four dice and the sums of the values of the dice need to be added together. A roll() method is used to do this. The directions for writing the roll method are as follows:

> "Ideally, the roll() method should take an argument stating how many dice you’d like to roll. The method should be a value returning method that returns the value of the die/dice and the sum to main().  You can roll all the dice at once, or one die at a time."

I decided to roll the four dice one at a time. In the example dice programs that my teacher showed me, there are different methods that return the values instead of just one. Each of my methods returns one value. However, when I tried to compile it, I got a few errors that said "cannot find symbol" for each time I have *return dieValue;* although I'm not sure why because I already looked over this and added "int" in the header and declared the variables multiple times in other areas of the program and still get the error. I also tried to compile this into less methods like my teacher suggested, but I got stuck when trying to figure out how to make an argument that states how many dice you'd like to roll. So I'm sticking with my current approach, but I'm still unsure of what's wrong.

Here's the portion of my code that deals with this:

```
        // Roll the dice (redirect to the roll() methods) and declare variables to hold the values that have returned. 
        int dieValue1 = roll_1();
        int dieValue2 = roll_2();
        int dieValue3 = roll_3();
        int dieValue4 = roll_4();

        // Declare a variable for the sum of the dice values (and add the dice values to get that sum).
        int diceSum = dieValue1 + dieValue2 + dieValue3 + dieValue4;

        // Print the sum of the rolled dice. 
        System.out.println("Your sum of the dice values: ");
        System.out.println(diceSum);

        // Determine if the user won or not. 
        if (diceSum == 6 ||diceSum == 12 ||diceSum == 13 ||diceSum == 17 || diceSum == 19 ||diceSum == 23)
            System.out.println("You win!");
            System.exit(0);

    }
    // roll() method header that rolls the die (creates a Die object and gets a random value for the object).
        public void roll()
        {
            // Create a Random class object. 
            Random dieRoll = new Random();

            // Get a random integer value for the dice between 1 and 6.
            int dieValue1 = dieRoll.nextInt(6) + 1;
            int dieValue2 = dieRoll.nextInt(6) + 1;
            int dieValue3 = dieRoll.nextInt(6) + 1;
            int dieValue4 = dieRoll.nextInt(6) + 1;
        }

    // method that returns the value of die1.
        public static roll_1()
        {
            return dieValue1;
        }
    // method that returns the value of die2.
        public static int roll_2()
        {
            return dieValue2;
        }
    // method that returns the value of die3.
        public int roll_3()
        {
            return static dieValue3;
        }
    // method that returns the value of die4.
        public static int roll_4()
        {
            return dieValue4;
        }
    // method that returns the sum of the values of die1, die2, die3, and die4. 
        public static int sum()
        {
            return dieValue1 + dieValue2 + dieValue3 + dieValue4;
        }
}
```

Thanks to anyone who decides to help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem exists because you declare dieValues inside roll method so their scope is only inside this method. And you return dieValue which actually does not exist. You need to create dieValue as a class variable and instead of "int" type in roll methods use "this" keyword to set class variables. And remember to declare them as static because your "roll" methods are static

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Roll {
    static int dieValue1;
    static int dieValue2;
    static int dieValue3;
    static int dieValue4;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        roll();
        int dieValue1 = roll_1();
        int dieValue2 = roll_2();
        int dieValue3 = roll_3();
        int dieValue4 = roll_4();

        // Declare a variable for the sum of the dice values (and add the dice values to
        // get that sum).
        int diceSum = dieValue1 + dieValue2 + dieValue3 + dieValue4;

        // Print the sum of the rolled dice.
        System.out.println("Your sum of the dice values: ");
        System.out.println(diceSum);

        // Determine if the user won or not.
        if (diceSum == 6 || diceSum == 12 || diceSum == 13 || diceSum == 17 || diceSum == 19 || diceSum == 23)
            System.out.println("You win!");
        System.exit(0);

    }

// roll() method header that rolls the die (creates a Die object and gets a random value for the object).
    public static void roll() {
        // Create a Random class object.
        Random dieRoll = new Random();

        // Get a random integer value for the dice between 1 and 6.
        dieValue1 = dieRoll.nextInt(6) + 1;
        dieValue2 = dieRoll.nextInt(6) + 1;
        dieValue3 = dieRoll.nextInt(6) + 1;
        dieValue4 = dieRoll.nextInt(6) + 1;
    }

// method that returns the value of die1.
    public static int roll_1()
    {
        return dieValue1;
    }

// method that returns the value of die2.
    public static int roll_2() {
        return dieValue2;
    }

// method that returns the value of die3.
    public static int roll_3()
    {
        return dieValue3;
    }

// method that returns the value of die4.
    public static int roll_4() {
        return dieValue4;
    }

// method that returns the sum of the values of die1, die2, die3, and die4. 
    public static int sum() {
        return dieValue1 + dieValue2 + dieValue3 + dieValue4;
    }
}
```

It is not best solution but I tried to run your program with the least amount of changes. I suggest to not use statics because it doesn't make sense here.

Below is my solution for your problem:

```
public class Roll {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int diceSum = roll();

        // Print the sum of the rolled dice.
        System.out.println("Your sum of the dice values: ");
        System.out.println(diceSum);

        // Determine if the user won or not.
        if (diceSum == 6 || diceSum == 12 || diceSum == 13 || diceSum == 17 || diceSum == 19 || diceSum == 23)
            System.out.println("You win!");
        System.exit(0);

    }

    public static int roll() {
        Random dieRoll = new Random();
        int diceSum = 0;

        diceSum += dieRoll.nextInt(6) + 1;
        diceSum += dieRoll.nextInt(6) + 1;
        diceSum += dieRoll.nextInt(6) + 1;
        diceSum += dieRoll.nextInt(6) + 1;
        return diceSum;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out about scope--it was an honest mistake. This looks like it'll work, I'll try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something that work.  Study it.  Understand it.  Please.

```
package com.inlet.ifserver;

import java.util.Random;

public class DieRoller {

    private Random dieRoll;

    private int dieValue1;
    private int dieValue2;
    private int dieValue3;
    private int dieValue4;

    // roll() method header that rolls the die (creates a Die object and gets a random value for the object).
    public DieRoller()
    {
        Random dieRoll = new Random();
        dieRoll.setSeed(System.currentTimeMillis());
    }

    public void roll() {

        // Get a random integer value for the dice between 1 and 6.
        dieValue1 = dieRoll.nextInt(6) + 1;
        dieValue2 = dieRoll.nextInt(6) + 1;
        dieValue3 = dieRoll.nextInt(6) + 1;
        dieValue4 = dieRoll.nextInt(6) + 1;

    }
    // method that returns the value of die1.
    public int roll_1()
    {
        return dieValue1;
    }
    // method that returns the value of die2.
    public int roll_2()
    {
        return dieValue2;
    }
    // method that returns the value of die3.
    public int roll_3()
    {
        return dieValue3;
    }
    // method that returns the value of die4.
    public int roll_4()
    {
        return dieValue4;
    }
    // method that returns the sum of the values of die1, die2, die3, and die4.
    public int sum()
    {
        return dieValue1 + dieValue2 + dieValue3 + dieValue4;
    }

    public static void main (String [] args) {

        DieRoller roller = new DieRoller();
        roller.roll();

        // Roll the dice (redirect to the roll() methods) and declare variables to hold the values that have returned.
        int dieValue1 = roller.roll_1();
        int dieValue2 = roller.roll_2();
        int dieValue3 = roller.roll_3();
        int dieValue4 = roller.roll_4();

        // Declare a variable for the sum of the dice values (and add the dice values to get that sum).
        int diceSum = roller.sum();

        // Print the sum of the rolled dice.
        System.out.println("Your sum of the dice values: ");
        System.out.println(diceSum);

        // Determine if the user won or not.
        if (diceSum == 6 ||diceSum == 12 ||diceSum == 13 ||diceSum == 17 || diceSum == 19 ||diceSum == 23)
            System.out.println("You win!");
    }
}
```

Can you explain to me all that's going on here?  Maybe you could take this and make it general.  Instead of 4 dice, N dice.  Instead of single dice variables, you could have an array of dice values "private int[] dieValues".  Pass the number of dice to the DieRoller's constructor as a parameter.

Comment: We haven't learned arrays in class yet so my teacher doesn't want us to use arrays in the program. But yes, I will keep in mind the DieRoller class for the next activity (which requires making a class for the dice).

Answer (score 0):

Within the `roll()` method, you defined 4 integer fields, `dieValue1`, `dieValue2` and so on. These variables are declared within the method itself, and thus can't be "read" within any other method, such as `roll_1()`, `roll_2()` and so on.

Even when you define the same variables again in other methods, they don't share anything, they will be treated as entirely different variables. That's also why you get those "Cannot find symbol" errors, because there is no `dieValue1` available within `roll_1()` and so on.

If you want to pass something back to the code that invoked a method like `roll()`, you have to use a `return` statement, for example:

```
public int roll() {
    // Create a Random class object. 
    Random dieRoll = new Random();

    // Get a random integer value for the dice between 1 and 6.
    return dieRoll.nextInt(6) + 1;
}
```

That's also exactly what was described within the directions:

> The method should be a **value returning method** that **returns the value** of the die/dice

Now, the next part of the exercise is to tell the `roll()` method how many times you wish to roll the die. To do this, you have to pass an argument, as mentioned in the directions:

> Ideally, the `roll()` method should take **an argument** stating how many dice you’d like to roll.

To do this, you have to change your method like this:

```
public int roll(int times) {
    // Create a Random class object. 
    Random dieRoll = new Random();

    // Get a random integer value for the dice between 1 and 6.
    return dieRoll.nextInt(6) + 1;
}
```

This also means that the methods `roll_1()`, `roll_2()` and so on are all obsolete, because you will have to pass the amount of times as an argument, and not declare a new method each time. You can delete these methods now.

That alone won't be enough though, since you're still only rolling the die once within your `roll()` method. To solve that, you could use a loop structure, that repeats the same action until certain threshold is met (in this case, until it reached n times):

```
public int roll(int times) {
    // Create a Random class object. 
    Random dieRoll = new Random();

    int dieSum = 0;
    for (int time = 1; time <= times; time++) {
        // Get a random integer value for the dice between 1 and 6.
        int dieValue = dieRoll.nextInt(6) + 1;
        dieSum = dieSum + dieValue;
    }
    return dieSum;
}
```

In this case, we used a `for` loop, declared a variable `time` that will increase each value by one each round, until it's no longer smaller or equal than `times`.

That also means that you don't need the `sum()` method, as the `roll()` method will now already calculate the sum for you. You can delete this method as well.

The final part is to actually invoke the method within your `main()` method, as stated by the directions:

```
int diceSum = roll(4);
if (diceSum == 6 || diceSum == 12 || diceSum == 13 || diceSum == 17 || diceSum == 19 || diceSum == 23)
    System.out.println("You win!");
System.exit(0);
```

Be aware, your indenting within your `main()` method is a bit confusing. If you don't use curly braces (`{}`) to surround the body of your `if` statement, then only one operation is executed. In this case that would be `System.out.println("You win!")`. The `System.exit(0)` operation is executed regardless of what the `diceSum` was.

Comment: Thank you! I think this is what my teacher's requirements for the project are, I will check. Thanks for catching my mistake, too.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following method for your application.

```
package com.example.demo;

public class myclass {

    int sum = 0;

    public void play(int numberofdices, int numberofeyes) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= numberofdices; i++) {
            sum = sum + (int) ((Math.random()) * numberofeyes + 1);
        }

        // Print the sum of the rolled dice.
        System.out.println("Your sum of the dice values: ");
        System.out.println(sum);

        // Determine if the user won or not.
        if (sum == 6 || sum == 12 || sum == 13 || sum == 17 || sum == 19 || sum == 23) {
            System.out.println("You win!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("You loose!");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm surely going to use a for-loop!